# Add templates folder in Django 1.8

Tags: python, django

I have some problem adding the templates directory for my django project. My goal is to override the  ***/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_form.html*** file.

My Django version is the 1.8. This is the templates part of my ***settings.py***:

```
 BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
 PROJECT_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates') 
 TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [PROJECT_PATH],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

In the templates folder inside my django project i add the modified ***password_reset_form.html***.

My ***urls.py*** is like this:

```
url(r'^password/reset/$',auth_views.password_reset,name='password_reset'),
url(r'^password/reset/done/$',auth_views.password_reset_done,name='password_reset_done'),
url(r'^password/reset/complete/$',auth_views.password_reset_complete,name='password_reset_complete'),
url(r'^password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$',auth_views.password_reset_confirm,name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

Answer (score 0):

I always do:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates') 
print "Templates in: %s" %(PROJECT_PATH)
```

To make sure I have them in the right spot. What does that print?  Also, post the output from `find /path/to/templates` where the path is the output from that print statement.

Comment: Nitpick, but for Python 2/3 compatibility:

Answer (score 0):

just copy the `admin/templates/registration/password_reset_form.html` to your `templates` folder and override it there. you dont need any change in settings

Comment: i did it but the web page does not change